# JRE 8 compatibility with weblogic 10.3.6 (11g

Tags: java, weblogic11g

Could you please help in finding out if JRE 8 would be compatible with weblogic 10.3?

We have a swing based application deployed on weblogic 10.3 server. We want to upgrade our JRE so wanted to check if JRE 8 would be able to run apps deployed on weblogic 10.3

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about supported deployment environments for a specific closed-source product.

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 is supported on WebLogic Server 12.1.3.  It is not supported on 10.3.6, 12.1.1, or 12.1.2.

See https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_12_1_3

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 is not yet supported in Weblogic server (till Weblogic 12.1.2).
It would be supported in future release.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3539686

Answer (score 0):

Bit old topic, but just came across this issue myself and have a bit more to add to it. As with the existing answers, it can't be used to install directly- the oracle installer will complain. 
However, it is possible to install using an earlier JDK (6 or 7 are supported in 10.3.6), and then swap to JDK8 under the covers. I expect you could also use a custom install to bypass the installer entirely.

This obviously isn't supported - but it does run. If you try to use certain JDK8 features though, they tend not to work (such as newer jdbc drivers - 4.2 simply won't run), so there isn't much benefit to this in normal use cases.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest update Weblogic 12C is compatible with JDK 8.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/notes/whatsnew.html#GUID-960100E8-DFC1-49E5-8CED-1EC1D883A42F