# How to update WebLogic server JDK from 1.7 to 1.8 on Windows 7?

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic-10.x, java-8

I wanted to upgrade the JDK version of my WebLogic server (10.3.6) from 1.7 to 1.8. What can be the possible steps required to do this?

I have existing weblogic and JDK old versions on Windows platform. I want to update them. But when I search document about update steps on internet, I couldn't find anything. They just mention about installing process.

Answer (score 3):

As you want to update weblogic and jdk version 1.7 to 1.8,

1. Then you can uninstall both of them.
2. Then download weblogic 12.2.1 and jdk 8 from following link.

   **Weblogic download link:** [weblogic download from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fusion-middleware/downloads/index.html)

   **JDK8 download link:** [jdk 8 download from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
3. Then install JDK8 first and then weblogic. Hope it is easy.

### [From Oracle blogs documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/emeapartnerweblogic/jdk-8-and-weblogic-1221-by-frank-munz),

- WebLogic 12.2.1 requires Java 8 (JDK 8) as a runtime.
- WebLogic 12.1.3 can be used with Java 7 or Java 8. Using WebLogic
  12.1.3 with Java 7 caused warnings because of the permspace settings in the WebLogic start scripts. Permspace is removed from JDK 8, so
  also these warnings are gone now with WebLogic 12.2.1 and JDK8.
- JDK 8 comes with Nashorn JavaScript engine. Try the jjs command line
  tool. [Read the complete article here](http://www.munzandmore.com/2015/ora/jdk-weblogic-12-2-1).

**You can also follow the link:** [JRE 8 compatibility with weblogic 10.3.6 (11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513660/jre-8-compatibility-with-weblogic-10-3-6-11g)

Answer (score 0):

I thought the support for Java 1.8 has begun with WLS 12.1.3.
So I assume its not possible/realistic to get wls10.x.x work with a newer jdk as 1.7.x.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3539686